# SQL ORDER BY NUMBER OF ENTRIES

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need to do the following data query in SQLite:

1. order by the authors that have the max number of books in library
2. In case of ties, order by the min number of days that you need to read all the books by a particular author
3. Then, order by the min number of days that you need to read a particular book;
4. Finally, order by the title of the books (book column).

So far this is what I got:

```
SELECT author, book from book_library
GROUP BY book
ORDER BY 
author DESC, 
COUNT(book), 
total_number_of_pages/speed ASC, 
(total_number_of_pages-pages_read)/speed ASC, 
book ASC;
```

It runs, but doesn't get me the desired outcome.

**Output should only have two columns, author AND book**

[Image Of The Data Structure]

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi!  You'll probably get more replies if you post what you have tried so far.  Right now, this post reads kinda like a homework question..

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to a inner query that groups on authors like below:

```
SELECT 
      author, 
      book 
   from 
      book_library B
         JOIN ( SELECT 
                      author,
                      count(book) AS bookcount,
                      sum((total_number_of_pages - pages_read) 
                             / speed) as min_days_to_read_all_books 
                   from 
                      book_library
                   group by 
                      author) A 
            ON B.author = A.author
   ORDER BY 
      A.bookcount DES,
      A.min_days_to_read_all_books,
      (B.total_number_of_pages - B.pages_read) / B.speed,
      B.book
```

The inner query orders the authors by total number of books, days it will take to finish reading all his books(remaining pages, you can remove the subtraction if want to read all the pages). We have a record for each author coming out of this inner query. Now to get a record for each book, only thing left to do is to join again to the table with author as the key, and order by number of days it will take to read remaining pages in the book and then the title.

The order by clauses can be arranged in the order needed.

Note - I updated the query to get the number of days it will take to read each book, somehow missed it before.

Comment: That's not quite it, some additional clarification would be helpful